# place HTML in jQuery modal dialog before open parameter

Tags: jquery

The following very simple code would trigger a very standard jQuery modal dialog:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      title: "Dialog Box",
      height:300,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Go": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Then the body of the dialog would have HTML like this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Some dialog">
  <p>Stuff goes here</p>
  <p>Stuff goes there</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way, with jQuery, to take the HTML and place it inside the main dialog function, so the dialog comes "pre-loaded" with the HTML?

**To clarify a bit:**

This may be the only or correct way to do this with jQuery modal dialogs, I just want to find out if there is another way.  Ideally, this is what my function would look like:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      title: "Dialog Box",
      height:300,
      modal: true,
      // some HTML goes here, do not know if such option exists
      buttons: {
        "Go": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Then the body of the dialog would in turn just have this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Some dialog">
</div>
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Cheers,

Claude

Comment: In modal dialogs the html is already in the page, hidden. What do you mean with pre-loading?

Comment: basically, I want the dialog to launch with some HTML elements already  in the body of the dialog.  Like a template, if you will.  Not the standard jQuery dialog options like buttons, width, height, but maybe an input box, select box, text, whatever.  Hope this is clearer :)

Comment: If you add what you want inside `<div id="dialog" title="Some dialog">` (instead of "some stuff code" ) it will, or am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: I clarified the question a little, hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside the open trigger you can append an ajax response or hardcoded html or html from somewhere on your page or whatever like:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cekp6/

```
            <script>  

            function infoBox(title,text,sel){

                $('#'+sel+'').dialog({
                open: function( event, ui ) {
                    if(text){
                        $('#'+sel+'').append(text);

                    }
                },
                beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {
                    if(text){
                        $('#'+sel+'').empty();
                    } 
                },
                show:'fade' , position:'center', resizable: false, modal:true,
                title:title
            });
            }
            $(function() {


                $('#btn1').click(function(){
                    var text = "<div><ul><li><span>heyo</span></li><li><span>heyooo</span></ul></div>";
                    var title = 'append html';
                    var sel = 'emptyDialog';
                    infoBox(title,text,sel)
                });

                $('#btn2').click(function(){
                    var title = 'use different dialoges';
                    var sel = 'dialog1';
                    infoBox(title,null,sel)

                });

                $('#btn3').click(function(){
                    var title = 'use different dialoges';
                    var sel = 'dialog2';
                    infoBox(title,null,sel)

                });

            });
            </script>
```

do not forget to remove the appended content before closing

Comment: Thank you John, this is very close to what I need, may be the correct thing :).  Does this only get triggered on open or are there options similar to "buttons", for instance, where this could be used.  Please forgive my ignorance on the topic, I am relatively new to jQuery.

Comment: the hardcoded html inside var p is appended when the dialoge opens, if you want to you can add and remove, or better show and hide things inside the button´s function as you have it in your code

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that when you have something `hidden` in a dialog box before you open it, the box is still going to be sized as if the content were visible (although there are ways around that).

Comment: i made an edit to show you how to outsource stuff and how you can avoid appending html but use different dialoges to use different html

Comment: Hey John, I cannot get this to work in a fiddle, would you mind posting a working fiddle version?

Answer (score 2):

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Dialog Box",
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function () {
        $("#dialog").append('<p>See, I was here all the time but you do not get to see me until I am opened! </p><p> <label>Got something to say?</label><input type="text" name = "gibberish" /></p>');
    },
    height: 300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Go": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
$("#open_sesame").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Some dialog"></div>
<input type="button" id="open_sesame" value="Open Dialog!" />
```

The way you are showing is exactly how it's done. Just make sure that `<div>` is on the same page as the call to the dialog box initialization.

If you're talking about dynamically loading the dialog box AFTER it's opened, you can do that with the `open :` event [(more on that)](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) and some well-formed AJAX.

[jsFiddle Demo to prove it!](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/4n7wD/1/)

Comment: thank you for your response!  I clarified question a little, hope this helps

Comment: I fixed it up for you... check the fiddle.

Comment: @mynameisneo It is customary to upvote responses that meet your needs and also accept the best answer.

Comment: DevIshOne, I upvoted your comment above a few hours back :).  I'm still working on the solution, once I do I will certainly accept one :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: Put the script in the Head Tags:

```
<!-- JQuery Modal Dialogs -->
<script>
function showDialog(url) {
var htmlstring = $('<div></div>').html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
$(htmlstring).dialog({
resizable: false, width: 960, height: 720, modal: true, show: { effect: "blind", duration: 500 }, hide: { effect: "blind", duration: 500 }
});
}
</script>
```

Set your a href Tags:

```
<a href="javascript:showDialog('<Your Data Here>');" class="hrefmodal">Link Display Name</a>
```

Hope this helps.